# Check if method uses while or for loop (Java)

Tags: java, junit

I'm correcting some tasks of my students and try to automate it via. JUnit testing. One condition of the task was to complete it without loops (for, while etc.) but with streams. Is there any way to check that dynamically? Or is that completely taken out by the compiler? Thought about maybe searching for specific keywords but for that i need the uncompiled code.

Comment: The simplest way would be to check through a regexpr on the source code. Decompiling source code to find used classes it too much effort, for something this simple. Secondly source code can tell you more about the program, like clean code principals used.

Comment: You can find loops fairly easily in compiled code because they must use one of the branching bytecode instructions. For that your test would have to incorporate a byte code parser library

Comment: Are you saying that you're getting only the compiled code from the students instead of the source code? That sounds very backwards, as you can easily compile the source yourself to verify it works as well as it adhering to required specifications, but decompiling the classes doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kayaman I can get the source, just wanted to know if there is an elegant way of doing this in JUnit.

Comment: @Joni Thoght about that aswell, but thats probably a bit too much for the use. But thanks.